# how to separating the matching points in optical flow?

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, computer-vision, opticalflow

I'm using `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()` function to track feature points. I'd like to separate matching only points from the results using the status vector resulted from `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()`.

The documentation from opencv [page](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-alpha/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html) says,

> output status vector (of unsigned chars); each element of the vector
>   is set to 1 if the flow for the corresponding features has been found,
>   otherwise, it is set to 0.

But when printed the status vector before implementation, I found that the status vector size is larger and 1s and 0s are scattered even after the array passes the size of feature points tracked.

If my tracked points vector size is 65, the status vector size is 100 and 1s and 0s are there even after status[64].

Will be help full if someone can help me out to get the right points only.

Thank You.

Comment: This status flag is not working well since it rejects a lot of usefull matches. It is better to use the forward backward confindence measure or to use all computed points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status vector should be of the same size as the feature vector.
If you see a size mismatch - please share the code you are using.

Here us how you can use it to filter out the "bad" features:

```
 calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(gray_1, gray_2, features_1, features_2, status, err, 
    wins_size, max_level, term_crit);

  // filter points with bad status
  size_t i, k;
  for( i = k = 0; i < features_2.size(); i++ ){
    if (!status[i]) continue;
    features_1[k] = features_1[i];
    features_2[k] = features_2[i];
    err[k] = err[i];
    k++;
  }
  features_1.resize(k);
  features_2.resize(k);
  err.resize(k);
```

Comment: Hello @Tom, thank you very much for the explanation. I checked the code back after your response. By mistakenly I added features to a wrong array. Thank You very much for the help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

In my implementation, I clear the **nextPts** and **status** vector before calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(). The size of prevPts, nextPts and status are exactly the same. If the data in status is 0, then the output flow is not valid.

```
vector<cv::Point2f> points_prev;
/* points_prev.push_back(some data) */
vector<cv::Point2f> points_next;
vector<uchar> status;
calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(img_prev, img_next, points_prev, points_next, status, err, winSize, 3, termcrit, 0, 0.001);
for (size_t i = 0; i < status.size(); i++)
{
    if(status.at(i) == 0)
        /*points_prev[i] is not valid*/
}
```

Comment: Thank You, @Yingci Bi, I really appreciate your help.